# How to change the pace of imported mov video clip in after effects

Tags: after-effects

Sorry for noob question or a possible duplicate.

We got a .mov inside a AE project. What we are trying to do is change the tempo of this so duration isn't 4 sec for example, but instead cause our audio is 6 seconds we would like it to simply scale in time so it becomes 6 seconds.

Is there a way to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method 1

The Last column on the right — in your pic it says **растягиваться** but in the English version of AE it's called **Stretch** — that's the one you need to modify Click on the number that says **100%**.

Alternatively, select the layer and from the **Layer** menu choose **Time>Time Stretch…** (I'm not sure what it is in Russian).

Then you'll get a dialog that lets you choose the duration you want, or a stretch factor if you want to choose the playback speed.

[image]

#### Method 2:

Apply Time Remapping to the layer (choose **Layer** from the menu or Right-Click the layer and then choose **Time>Enable Time Remapping** or hit <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt/option</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).

This will create a keyframe at the start and end of the layer.

Drag the last keyframe to the point where you want the layer to end.

#### Method 3

Park the playhead at the time you want the layer to end.

With the layer selected hit <kbd>ctrl/command</kbd><kbd>alt/option</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, which will stretch the out point to the current time.

You can do the same with the in point using <kbd>ctrl/command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: It is called "stretch" in the english version. I checked.  If you ever edit this post, you can remove that question mark.  I just don't want to edit it to make a single-character change.

Comment: The question mark was because the sentence starts with "See the last column…" I've rewritten it, thanks.